# App crashes on iPhone 5S but not on iPhone 4S.

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have an iPhone app that I have developed and tested on my iPhone 4S. The app is released on the market and some users claim that the app is unusable as it crashes on start up.

I have done exactly the same things as the users have to their devices, running the same version of the app on my iPhone 4S and I cannot get it to crash.

I have been to the houses of users and plugged their phones into my computer to get the log read out and when I do, I get errors that I am not getting on my phone and my mac.

I am completely at a loss as to how I start to find the solution to a problem like this. Does anyone have even the faintest ideas?

Comment: Did you get the crash report from such a device? You can get it either via Xcode organizer or the user can go do "Settings" -> "General" -> "About" -> "Diagnostic & Usage" -> "Diagnostic & Usage Data". Search the report for your app, copy & paste the text and send it via email. Once you have the report, please add it to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. A good start will be to integrate a crash log collecting, crash reporting SDK in your app like **[HockeyApp](http://hockeyapp.net/features/)**, **[TestFlight](http://testflightapp.com/)**, **[Crittercism](https://www.crittercism.com/)** or **[QuincyKit](http://quincykit.net/)**.

   This will send you the crash logs to you so you don't have to collect them manually. These tools can also automatically symbolicate the crash logs for you so you can find the source of the crash in your code.
2. You should test a release build before you ship it. Archive a release build and distribute it as an Ad-Hoc build. You can load a saved IPA file to your iDevice using iTunes or Organizer. The thing is that you can test a release build which is the same you would ship to the App Store (they are signed differently but the build configuration is the same unless you changed that).
3. iPhone 5S ships with 64-bit A7 processor. Your iPhone 4 is a 32-bit device. Most likely processor architecture is not the case but as Apple says: *Before you distribute your app, you must test it on actual hardware. Some of the runtime changes can be detected only when the app is running on a device.* I recommend you updating your set of test devices with different models. I still own an old iPhone 3GS which is great for spotting performance issues.

Comment: Please note that depending on the type of startup crash, no crash reporting library can provide you those reports. HockeyApp provides support to get some of them, see http://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-ios-mac-os-x/how-to-handle-crashes-during-startup-on-ios But if the app crashes even before reaching `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`, only Apples crash reports can help.

Comment: A note regarding the 64-bit A7 processor: If the application does not provide a 64-bit slice in the binary, it will run in 32-bit mode. Also all the system frameworks will run in 32-bit mode too!

Answer (score 2):

The general comments others have posted are correct. Add crash logging into your app with a pre-made SDK and test on an actual device. I can't add much more to those points, but I will tell a short story about a similar bug that I found in one of my apps in the hopes it helps you with your issue.

Our app was predominately iPad2 users. When the iPad4 was released, waves of our users upgraded and they started experiencing an issue that was not present on iPad2. Two network requests were fired off at the same time and the result from one of them was crashing. We eventually found out it was a concurrency bug. The result of the first request was being processed "too quickly" and the code was getting to a critical section of code that was not thread-safe with the other request handler.

While this bug was still possible on the iPad2 if the network latency fluctuated just right, it never happened that way. The iPad4 made it happen almost every time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack lib to  collect crash data logs from users.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered installing a crash logger in your app? There are plenty out there (Flurry, TestFlight, Crittercism, Hockey App, etc).

Most are fairly straightforward to install - add a framework and a couple of lines of code. Once you've done this, you'll (hopefully) be able to see exactly where your app is crashing on the users' devices, without having physical access to them.